# css last ul styling

Tags: html, css

I would like to add different styling to my last ul element with the class name `footer_list` , but none of the following things are working

```
ul.footer_list:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

#menu-bottom.pads ul.footer_list:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

the structure looks as it follows

```
<div class="pads clearfix" id="menu-bottom">
    <ul class="footer_list">
        <li><a title="" href=""></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="footer_list">
        <li><a title="Zu den Dell Gutschein Codes" href="/dell-gutschein-codes/"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="footer_list">
        <div class="menu-footer-container">
            <ul class="menu" id="menu-footer">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25" id="menu-item-25"><a href=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use the last-of-type pseudo selector.

```
.footer_list:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong selector. Rather than:

```
ul.footer_list:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

It should be:

```
.footer_list:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

For an example to see the selector working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/kDhS8/

Comment: thanks for the feedback and for your help I'm testing it under firefox but doesn't seems to work

Comment: Firefox certainly does support it. Unless you are using a much older version. However, the answer you've accepted wouldn't work for you in  Firefox either if this code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works ! (http://jsfiddle.net/NJcVE/1/)

> .footer_list:last-child {
>       border-right: none; }

and for IE7/8 you can add a class to last ul you want. 
Example:
CSS:

```
.lt-ie9 .last-child {border-right: none;}
```

Jquery:

```
/* LAST CHILD HACK FOR IE7/8 */
$(function(){
    if( $.browser.msie ){
     if( $.browser.version == 7.0 || $.browser.version == 8.0 ){
        $('.footer_list').each(function(){
            if( $(this).is(':last-child') ){
                $(this).addClass('last-child');
            }       
        });
     } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `last-child`, it means in your `ul` all of the `li`s are children, so you have to unify your `ul` and the last `li` is your `last-child`, something like this:

**CSS:**

```
.footer_list li{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.footer_list li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="footer_list">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use This

```
#menu-bottom ul:last-child  {
    //css for Last ul tag
}
```